# Android: Generated QR code using Zxing has margins (is not fit to the area)

Tags: android, bitmap, zxing, qr-code

I'm using in my app ZXing library for generating QR code. I want to generated QR code that should fits to the width of the screen (maybe some small padding).

If I set width of the screen as width size of QR code I get smaller QR code. Look at the screenshot (it's 320x240 resolution). I want QR code to fit the black area. Why is QR code in red so small?

How do I stretch it to the black area?

[image: From the app]

My code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x; 

Bitmap bm = encodeAsBitmap(mGeneratedURL, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, width);
qrcodeImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Generating QR code:

```
private Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        //hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0); /* default = 4 */
    }
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }

    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? RED : Color.BLACK;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I find a problem!

This line:

```
 String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
```

returns null

So It doesn´t set

```
EncodeHintType.MARGIN.
```

Remove the codition and it should be ok.

```
//if (encoding != null) {
    hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
    //hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0); /* default = 4 */
//}
```

Comment: Just be aware the reason this margin exists. The margin area (known as the quiet zone) is placed on the image by design to provide the best possible results when scanning. Reducing or removing the quiet zone may make it more difficult for some scanners to quickly and accurately scan your code in sub-optimal conditions such as low light, however in most instances it will not make a difference.